# Android Google Firebase build

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, firebase

Trying to create a build in Jenkins to build with the Google Firebase Libraries.

I end up with the following errors in jenkins:

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml
12:47:23    File1: /Users/androidadmin/jenkins_slave_macmini2/workspace/firebase quick/flagship_commons/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-basement/9.0.2/jars/classes.jar
12:47:23    File2: /Users/androidadmin/jenkins_slave_macmini2/workspace/firebase quick/flagship_commons/build/intermediates/bundles/google/debug/classes.jar
```

I added the following to my app/build.gradle:

```
//Exclude duplicate files for firebase
android {    
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
    }
}
```

And when I do a ./gradlew clean build locally on my Mac it works fine, but I run in Jenkins, I still get the same error above.

Comment: Did you find any better solution to this ?